# Create IEnumerable<T>.Find()

Tags: c#, extension-methods, ienumerable

I'd like to write:

```
IEnumerable<Car> cars;
cars.Find(car => car.Color == "Blue")
```

Can I accomplish this with extension methods? The following fails because it recursively calls itself rather than calling IList.Find().

```
public static T Find<T>(this IEnumerable<T> list, Predicate<PermitSummary> match)
{
    return list.ToList().Find(match);
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 65, accepted):

This method already exists.  It's called FirstOrDefault

```
cars.FirstOrDefault(car => car.Color == "Blue");
```

If you were to implement it yourself it would look a bit like this

```
public static T Find<T>(this IEnumerable<T> enumerable, Func<T,bool> predicate) {
  foreach ( var current in enumerable ) {
    if ( predicate(current) ) {
      return current;
    }
  }
  return default(T);
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Didn't realize this overload existed.

Comment: Great Answer!  I never realized this overload existed and have been adding superfluous .Where(...).First() statements.

Answer (score 10):

Jared is correct if you are looking for a single blue car, any blue car will suffice. Is that what you're looking for, or are you looking for a list of blue cars?

First blue car:

```
Car oneCar = cars.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Color.Equals("Blue"));
```

List of blue cars:

```
IEnumerable<Car> manyCars = cars.FindAll(car => car.Color.Equals("Blue"));
```

Comment: Thanks, and if you are looking for exactly one blue car:
cars.Single(car => car.Color.Equals("Blue")

Comment: Single is okay if you are guaranteed to have ONLY ONE car in the entire list.  If you have more than one car, or no cars at all, you're going to throw an InvalidOperationException.    FirstOrDefault will return your blue car, or the default type (often null).  First will throw an exception if there is nothing that matches the predicate.

Answer (score 4):

You know that `Find(...)` can be replaced by `Where / First`

```
IEnumerable<Car> cars;
var result = cars.Where(c => c.Color == "Blue").FirstOrDefault();
```

This'll return `null` in the event that the predicate doesn't match.

Comment: No need for the Where.  FirstOrDefault will take the Predicate too.

Comment: You can specify the predicate directly on `FirstOrDefault()` and leave `Where()` out.