# newbie: Creating enum.FirstOrDefault(), getting an "Cannot implicitly convert type"

Tags: c#, lambda, ienumerator

I want to find and return the first `CartLine` that has a match of product in a `Cart` with the `FindProductInCartLines(int productId)` method. If occurrence can't be found return `null`.

However, the compiler throws an error

> Cannot implicitly convert type: CartLine to Product

with the `FirstOrDefault()` line number.

I'm a real newbie concerning lambda functions and delegates. I thought it was already dereferenced with `line.Product.Id` but obviously I'm having some kind of misunderstanding.

I tried using JaredPar's answer from: [Create IEnumerable<T>.Find()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2969643/create-ienumerablet-find)
But I don't see the difference between my code and his.

```
public class CartLine 
{
    public int OrderLineId { get; set; }
    public Product Product { get; set; }
    public int Quantity { get; set; }
}

public IEnumerable<CartLine> Lines => GetCartLineList();

private List<CartLine> GetCartLineList()
{
    return new List<CartLine>();
}

public Product FindProductInCartLines(int productId)
{
    return Lines.FirstOrDefault(line => line.Product.Id == productId);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

When you call `FirstOrDefault()` it will return an object of the same type as the source, in your case that is `Lines` which is of type `CartLine` - which is why you get the error. To get the child property from the parent you need add a reference to the property to your call (allowing for nulls).

So, in your case you would need:

```
public Product FindProductInCartLines(int productId)
{
    return Lines.FirstOrDefault(line => line.Product.Id == productId)?.Product;
}
```

If you are unsure of the `?.` operator you can read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28352116/2309376) for a great explanation.

Answer (score 0):

```cs
// The method return type is Product
 public Product FindProductInCartLines(int productId){
               return Lines.FirstOrDefault(line => line.Product.Id == productId);// this line return CartLine object;
           }
```

You should change return type of method to CartLine

```cs
 public CartLine FindProductInCartLines(int productId){
               return Lines.FirstOrDefault(line => line.Product.Id == productId);
           }
```

If you want it return Product

```cs
 public Product FindProductInCartLines(int productId){
               return Lines.FirstOrDefault(line => line.Product.Id == productId)?.Product;
           }
```